How can I perform bulk insertion combined with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`?
I have a substantial collection of financial market data in multiple CSV files that I need to store in a database for future use in my software.
I am employing Python with SQLAlchemy and SQLite.
Here's what my data looks like, along with my database models:
            Open    High    Low     Close
Timestamp               
31798800    0.53690 0.53690 0.53690 0.53690
31802400    0.53690 0.53690 0.53690 0.53690
31885200    0.53660 0.53660 0.53660 0.53660
31888800    0.53660 0.53660 0.53660 0.53660
31971600    0.53650 0.53650 0.53650 0.53650
... ... ... ... ...
1731113460  1.07177 1.07185 1.07174 1.07182
1731113520  1.07182 1.07182 1.07177 1.07178
1731113580  1.07179 1.07187 1.07178 1.07186
1731113640  1.07186 1.07186 1.07178 1.07180
1731113700  1.07181 1.07181 1.07181 1.07181

import datetime
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Float, Date, Time
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Date(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dates"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    date: Mapped[datetime.date] = mapped_column(Date, nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Date<id={self.id!r}, date={self.date!r}>"


class Time(Base):
    __tablename__ = "times"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    time: Mapped[datetime.time] = mapped_column(Time, nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Time<id={self.id!r}, time={self.time!r}>"


class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = "regions"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    markets: Mapped[List["Market"]] = relationship()

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Region<id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, markets={self.markets!r}>"

class Market(Base):
    __tablename__ = "markets"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=False)
    region: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("regions.id"))
    assets: Mapped[List["Asset"]] = relationship()

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Market<id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, region={self.region!r}, assets={self.assets!r}>"


class Asset(Base):
    __tablename__ = "assets"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    symbol: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=True)
    market: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("markets.id"))

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Asset<id={self.id!r}, symbol={self.symbol!r}, name={self.name!r}, market={self.market!r}>"


class MarketData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "market_data"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    date: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("dates.id"))
    time: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("times.id"))
    asset: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("assets.id"))
    opening: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    high: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    low: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    closing: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    volume: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Market Value<id={self.id!r}, date={self.date!r}, time={self.time!r}, asset={self.asset!r}, opening={self.opening!r}, high={self.high!r}, low={self.low!r}, closing={self.closing!r}, volume={self.volume!r}>"


I utilized the following code for the initial dates insertion.
symbol = "EURUSD"
filenames = get_symbol_data_filenames(symbol)
total_df = None
for filename in filenames:
    df = read_csv(filename)
    df = df.set_index(["Timestamp"])
    if total_df is None:
        total_df = df
    else:
        total_df = concat([df, total_df])
total_df = total_df.sort_index()
total_df = total_df[~total_df.index.duplicated(keep="last")]
database_engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data/db.sqlite3")
Base.metadata.create_all(database_engine)
with Session(database_engine) as session:
    global_region = session.query(Region).filter_by(name="Global").first()
    if global_region is None:
        global_region = Region(name="Global")
        session.add(global_region)
        session.commit()
    forex = session.query(Market).filter_by(name="Forex", region=global_region.id).first()
    if forex is None:
        forex = Market(name="Forex", region=global_region.id)
        session.add(forex)
        session.commit()
    eurusd = session.query(Asset).filter_by(symbol="EURUSD", name="Euro/US-Dollar", market=forex.id).first()
    if eurusd is None:
        eurusd = Asset(symbol="EURUSD", name="Euro/US-Dollar", market=forex.id)
        session.add(eurusd)
        session.commit()
    dates = [date.fromtimestamp(ts) for ts in dft.index]
    seen = set()
    dates = [x for x in dates if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
    session.bulk_insert_mappings(Date, [{"date": date_} for date_ in dates])
    session.commit()

However, this dataset is regularly updated, and I need to insert new data into the database while ensuring data integrity, which currently is too slow.
This is what I tried to do for inserting new data into the database.
with Session(database_engine) as session:
    dates = session.query(Date).all()
    if dates is None:
        new_dates = [date.fromtimestamp(ts) for ts in total_df.index]
        seen = set()
        new_dates = [x for x in new_dates if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
        session.bulk_insert_mappings(Date, [{"date": date_} for date_ in new_dates])
        session.commit()
    else:
        dates = [x.date for x in dates]
        new_dates = [date.fromtimestamp(ts) for ts in total_df.index]
        seen = set()
        new_dates = [x for x in new_dates if x not in seen and x not in dates and not seen.add(x)]
        session.bulk_insert_mappings(Date, [{"date": date_} for date_ in new_dates])
        session.commit()

How can I perform bulk insertion combined with ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING? I think this is the most efficient method I can use.

I suggest you split the task into three steps:

Create a temporary staging table
Copy CSV file/files into staging table
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM staging ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

This way you will benefit from the batch insertion of COPY and still have to flexibility of SELECT statement

To combine ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING to ensure data integrity and improve insertion efficiency during batch insertions, you can follow these steps to modify.
First, you need to make sure that the database you're using (SQLite in this case) supports the ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING statement. For your existing code, suppose you want to insert the table is MarketData, can modify bulk_insert_mappings part code like this: the from sqlalchemy. Dialects. Sqlite import inserts
Build a list of data to insert
data_to_insert = [
    {
        "date": date.fromtimestamp(ts),
        "time": some_time,
        "asset": some_asset_id,
        "opening": some_opening_value,
        "high": some_high_value,
        "low": some_low_value,
        "closing": some_closing_value,
        "volume": some_volume_value,
    }
    for ts, some_time, some_asset_id, some_opening_value, some_high_value, some_low_value, some_closing_value, some_volume_value in your_data_source
]

Perform the insert operation
insert_stmt = insert(MarketData).values(data_to_insert)
on_conflict_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(
    index_elements=["date"]
)  # Assume that the 'date' column is a possible conflict column
session.execute(on_conflict_stmt)
session.commit()

In the above code, you first create an insert statement insert_stmt and then use the on_conflict_do_nothing method to specify that no operation is performed in the event of a conflict (based on the specified column date).
Finally, the statement is executed through session.execute and the transaction is committed.
In this way, when the newly inserted data conflicts with the existing data in the date column, no operation is performed. In this way, the insertion efficiency is improved while data integrity is ensured.
Note that you need to modify the column values in the data_to_insert and specify appropriate columns that may conflict based on the actual table structure and data.

sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.insert

Construct a sqlite-specific variant Insert construct. The sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.insert() function creates a sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.Insert. The Insert construct includes additional methods Insert.on_conflict_do_update(), Insert.on_conflict_do_nothing().

from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import insert

session.execute(insert(Date).values(
    [{"date": date_} for date_ in new_dates]).on_conflict_do_nothing())


I followed your suggestion, but there’s a small problem. If any record in the data has a conflict, it rolls back all processes and doesn't insert anything. I need that if one record conflicts, it simply ignores it and proceeds with the other records.

The default conflict resolution algorithm in sqlite is ABORT. Change it in your Date.id primary key column by setting sqlite_on_conflict_primary_key='IGNORE'.

I’m still uncertain. I included it in my test scenario but did not modify anything. I haven’t tested it with the main scenario yet as it relies on another issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79242440/is-it-feasible-to-generate-a-separate-table-for-each-entity-in-the-database-usin

You will have to recreate the table to change conflict resolution.
