Is it feasible to generate a separate table for each entity in the database using a single ORM class?
I developed a database with the ORM system to manage financial market data.
I am employing Python with SQLAlchemy and SQLite.
I need to retrieve the latest record for each asset from the market_data table, extract its date and time, request updated data from the server, and then insert the new data back into the market_data table. I plan to perform this operation multiple times per minute, so speed is essential. However, the current query takes several minutes to execute. I've identified that the filtering process for each asset is the primary bottleneck; without it, the query completes instantly but returns incorrect results.
I think storing each asset's data in a separate table would be more efficient, but I can't create a specific class for every asset since they can be added dynamically at runtime.
Is there a way to generate multiple tables from one ORM class? Alternatively, do you have any suggestions to enhance the database structure to improve the speed of this query?
The current models for the database:
class Date(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dates"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    date: Mapped[datetime.date] = mapped_column(Date, nullable=False, unique=True)

class Time(Base):
    __tablename__ = "times"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    time: Mapped[datetime.time] = mapped_column(Time, nullable=False, unique=True)

class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = "regions"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    markets: Mapped[List["Market"]] = relationship()

class Market(Base):
    __tablename__ = "markets"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=False)
    region: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("regions.id"))
    assets: Mapped[List["Asset"]] = relationship()

class Asset(Base):
    __tablename__ = "assets"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    symbol: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=True)
    market: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("markets.id"))

class MarketData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "market_data"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    date: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("dates.id"))
    time: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("times.id"))
    asset: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("assets.id"))
    opening: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    high: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    low: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    closing: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=False)
    volume: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=True)

The query that I tested to take the last x record of one asset:
session.query(MarketData).filter_by(asset=asset.id).order_by(desc(MarketData.id)).limit(10).all()


Dynamically Create An ORM Class
mapped_class = type("Asset", (Asset, Base), {"__tablename__": "assets"})

>>> "assets" in Base.metadata.tables
True
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Table
>>> isinstance(Base.metadata.tables["assets"], Table)
True
>>> Base.metadata.tables["assets"] is mapped_class.__table__
True

If you have a different table for each asset, just by changing the table name, you can create another ORM class referencing that table.
type("Asset", (Asset, Base), {"__tablename__": "another_assets"})
>>> isinstance(Base.metadata.tables["another_assets"], Table)
True

For a given table name, only one instance of Table in the metadata can exist at a time:
>>> type("Asset", (Asset, Base), {"__tablename__": "another_assets"})
{InvalidRequestError}InvalidRequestError("Table 'another_assets' is already defined for this MetaData instance. Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.")

Query
>>> from sqlalchemy import select
>>> session.scalars(select(mapped_class).filter_by(name="asset_name")).one_or_none()

You can also use Table instance here if created earlier:
session.scalars(select(Base.metadata.tables["assets"]).filter_by(name="asset_name")).one_or_none()

Dynamically Create A Table In db
Just by loading the instance of Table in metadata is not enough to send queries. Your table must exist in the database as well. By using the ORM class created earlier, you can also create a table dynamically.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(url=...)
mapped_class = type("Asset", (Asset, Base), {"__tablename__": "new_assets"})

with engine.begin() as conn:
    mapped_class.__table__.create(bind=conn, checkfirst=True)


I get this error NoForeignKeysError: Can't determine the inherit condition between inherited table 'market_data' and inheriting table 'xauusd'; tables have no foreign key relationships established.  Please ensure the inheriting table has a foreign key relationship to the inherited table, or provide an 'on clause' using the 'inherit_condition' mapper argument. when trying mapped_class = type("XAUUSD", (MarketData, Base), {"__tablename__": "xauusd"})

Do not inherit Base in MarketData. Treat it as a regular mixin class template to create dyanmic ORM classes.
